# Repeating until correct answer is given

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop

Here is a code that I made, it's just a small part of the whole bigger thing. How do I put this in a while loop so that it will repeat the `"Invalid answer, try again."` until the correct answer is given? I have tried for many hours looking at while loops but just can't do it. If you actually will run the code it obviously will come up with errors because you don't have paths etc.

Here is the code:

```
shortestpath = raw_input("Give the shortest path? (Y/N)")
if shortestpath == "Y" or shortestpath == "y":
    answer = min(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7, path8, path9)
    print "The shortest path is: "
    print answer
    if answer == path1:
        print "a,f,e"
    elif answer == path2:
        print "a,c,f,e"
    elif answer == path3:
        print "a,f,c,d,e"
    elif answer == path4:
        print "a,f,c,b,d,e"
    elif answer == path5:
        print "a,c,d,e"
    elif answer == path6:
        print "a,c,b,d,e"
    elif answer == path7:
        print "a,b,c,f,e"
    elif answer == path8:
        print "a,b,c,d,e"
    elif answer == path9:
        print "a,b,d,e"
elif shortestpath == "N" or shortestpath == "n":
    print "End of program."
else:
    print "Invalid answer, try again."
```

Comment: use `break` to leave `while True` when answer is correct.

Comment: BTW: you could use list `path` and `path[1]`, `path[2]`, etc. with `for-loop` to check answer. And `answer = min(path)`

Comment: BTW: you can do `if shortestpath.lower() == "y":` or `if shortestpath in ("Y", "y"):`

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in a `while` loop. Once your code reaches a correct answer, you can exit the loop with `break`

```
while True:
    shortestpath = raw_input("Give the shortest path? (Y/N)")
    if shortestpath == "Y" or shortestpath == "y":
        answer = min(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7, path8, path9)
        print "The shortest path is: "
        print answer
        if answer == path1:
            print "a,f,e"
        elif answer == path2:
            print "a,c,f,e"
        elif answer == path3:
            print "a,f,c,d,e"
        elif answer == path4:
            print "a,f,c,b,d,e"
        elif answer == path5:
            print "a,c,d,e"
        elif answer == path6:
            print "a,c,b,d,e"
        elif answer == path7:
            print "a,b,c,f,e"
        elif answer == path8:
            print "a,b,c,d,e"
        elif answer == path9:
            print "a,b,d,e"
        break
    elif shortestpath == "N" or shortestpath == "n":
        print "End of program."
        break
    else:
        print "Invalid answer, try again."
```

Comment: you need only one `break` inside `if shortestpath == "Y"` and another in `elif shortestpath == "N"`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_answer(prompt,options):
    while True:
        result = raw_input(prompt)
        if result in options: return result
        print "Got unexpected input ... please try again"

selected_option = get_answer("Would you like to _____?",options=["y","Y","n","N"])
```